# How could I accept cookies with jsoup?

Tags: java, html, cookies, jsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to **scrape** comments from a digital newspaper. I'm doing it in Java with Jsoup. The problem is I've to accept cookies from the site to search notices... The site is https://elpais.com/buscador/

I've tryied connecting with Jsoup.connect(url) and taking the cookies from the response to do another request with those cookies but I didn't succedd.

```
    Connection conexion = null;
    Document doc = null;
    Response response = null;
    Map<String, String> cookies = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    try {

        // First request.
        Connection connection1 = Jsoup.connect(url);
        for (Entry<String, String> cookie : cookies.entrySet()) {
            connection1.cookie(cookie.getKey(), cookie.getValue());
        }
        Response response1 = connection1.execute();
        cookies.putAll(response1.cookies());


        // Second request.
        Connection connection2 = Jsoup.connect(url);
        for (Entry<String, String> cookie : cookies.entrySet()) {
            connection2.cookie(cookie.getKey(), cookie.getValue());
        }
        Response response2 = connection2.execute();
        cookies.putAll(response2.cookies());
        doc = response2.parse();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
               System.out.println("Exception raised: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return doc;
```

I've seen this code from some posts but it didn't help me :(
I would like to request the url "https://elpais.com/buscador/?qt=Espa%C3%B1a+Politica&sf=1&np=1&bu=ep&of=html" and get the response with the notices.
Thank you.

Comment: Nope, i just received the html but without the notices, because you need to accept cookies to received them in the response.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and I got it, but I need to do it with Java :(

Comment: Yep, exactly, the second one